# What is the difference between normal Select query and a Select query inside Common Table Expression(CTE)?

Tags: sql-server, select, cte

I'm having a table 'Products' and if Execute this query

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ProductID]
      ,[ProductDesc]
      ,[ManufacturingDate]
      ,[ExpiryDate]
      ,[Price]
  FROM [TestSat].[dbo].[Products]
```

I got the output:

[image]

and If I use this `select` query:

```
SELECT ProductDesc,Price
  FROM [Products]
  WHERE Price>20.00
```

I got this output:

[image]

If I use CTE-Select like this:

```
 ;WITH ProductsCTE(ProdName,Price) AS
( SELECT ProductDesc,Price
  FROM [Products]
  WHERE Price>20.00
)
```

I got this output:

[image]

The only difference I found between this simple Select Query as well as CTE Select query is the Column name (ProductDesc as ProdName). 
Does it is the only difference between normal Select query as well as CTE Select query?

Comment: Did you tried checking execution plan. CTE is kind of temp table and for moment you are storing a part of data in it and then selecting the data.

Comment: Weird question, IMHO, have you searched a bit about what is a CTE, how it works and how can be used? And I mean on SE site, not even using your prefered search engine for a global search. Look for CTE vs temp tables, CTE vs subquery, CTE recursive, CTE performance, [How CTE really works?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7804155/1297603).